# Android - Creating an alert dialog in listview from selected item

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

Ive been struggling to get an alert dialog to pop up when the user clicks an item in the list view. I can do a toast message but cant seem to get an alert dialog to work. I then want to have a button in the alert dialog to allow me to take the item just selected and display it on the next screen where it will be show contact details etc for the one selected. If anyone can give me any insight into any good techniques or tips on how to do this it would be awesome! Im a very new programmer and ive tried everywhere.

Below is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] taxi = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listtaxi, taxi));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        });
    } 
}
```

The array is in the strings.xml file.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The code you paste is for showing a Toast. Did you try the one for showing an alert dialog? What errors do you get?

Comment: it just didnt show anything up when i tried it.  yeah i tried an alertdialog but all it did was show the list and when i clicked it, it did nothing. cant quite get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in general is correct. I'd make sure your code for posting a dialog works correctly first. Try it out in a way outside of the list, and then see if it works in the onClick() statement itself.

Comment: you're a legend! had a play about and managed to get it to work. had to change my listview to final listview and it seems fine!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(lv.getContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `YourClass.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: you'd get the context of the actual Activity instead of the whole application. that was the source of some issues I had with Toasts / dialogs not showing up.